# With Heroku's recent collaborator privilege change: How can a collaborator scale an app?

Tags: heroku

I went to scale my Heroku rails app, like I normally do, but WHAM! Heroku changed the privileges on me:

```
Scaling worker processes... done, now running 1
!    Scaling an app as a collaborator is not supported; it’ll be removed soon. Please see: http://bit.ly/PWf1tR.
```

According to [Heroku's collaborators privileges page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sharing#collaborator-privileges):

> ### Collaborator privileges
>
> All actions are supported for collaborators as they are for app owners
> except:
>
> - Scaling dynos
> - Adding or removing paid add-ons
> - Deleting or renaming the app
> - Viewing invoices
>
> These actions are only supported for app owners.

Okay, so what now? Everyone on my team needs to scale the app and I'm not excited about everyone sharing the owner credentials.

Is there a way *--Heroku feature, 3rd party tool, total hack, etc.--* that collaborators can scale Heroku apps since the recent privilege change?

Comment: Can you contact Heroku Support about this?

Comment: Idk why I didnt do that first (maybe because I thought Heroku wouldn't recommend 3rd party solutions), but I did just now. I'll update this question with their response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Heroku's response to my question:

> Based on feedback from you and other users we've decided to avoid
>   making any changes to the collaborator semantics until we're able to
>   offer a stronger alternative path for managing access control. The
>   deprecation notice will be removed shortly.

They were super helpful and apologized for the inconvenience too.